# Cannot cast object of T to concrete type

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to understand generic types. However, I think I'm getting confused with fakes.

On my system, I'd like to load something. It doesn't matter what it is, and it could be anything. The caller will konw what it is.

My approach is to use an interface, where the interface is simply

```
public interface ILoad
{
    void Load<T>(T t);  
}
```

In my Bll class, I have a method which is

```
public void Start(ILoad load)
{
    load.Load<Survey>(this);     // I'm telling it the type and passing it the object
}

public class FakeLoadForSurvey : ILoad     //this class knows about Survey 
{
    public void Load<T>(T t)
    {
         t = new Survey();            //fails
    {
}
```

It fails with the following error message

> Cannot implicity convert type Survey to T

I hope the above example is clear enough.

How do I tell C# that `T` is of type `Survey` (or any other type)?

Comment: `t = (T)(object)new Survey();`

Comment: I think you need to add constraint for T. where T : Survey or some base class

Comment: Any reason it's not `ILoad<T>` though? Why only constrain the *method*? (If you need a non-generic base for Reasons, you can still have an `ILoad` that `ILoad<T>` inherits from, though it would be an empty marker interface.)

Comment: Thank you @JeroenMostert, that's a great comment

Comment: If you know that `T` is `Survey`, why is the method generic at all?

Comment: Consider also that you may actually want `Load(object)` or `Load(MyEntityBaseClass)` or in rarer cases even `Load(dynamic)`. If the caller cannot actually use the static type of the object at all (because we could be "passing anything"), there's little point in pretending the generic method will actually give you static typing. Generics are easily overused. (You can still have overloads or interfaces that use more concrete types.)

Comment: @DavidG, as per my post `It doesn't matter what it is, and it could be anything`. So, it could be `Survey`, or `Car`, or `Truck`, or `WeightLifter`, or `Computer`. The point is, what ever the object, it implements ILoad, where the object can be constructed by the caller :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> public class FakeLoadForSurvey : ILoad     //this class knows about Survey
> ```

If the class implementing the interface knows the type for `T`, then move `T` to the interface:

```
public interface ILoad<T>
{
    void Load(T t);  
}

public class FakeLoadForSurvey : ILoad<Survey>
{
    public void Load(Survey t)
    {
         t = new Survey();
    }
}
```

Do note however that this won't affect the argument passed to `Load()`.

So if some code calls it like this:

```
var surveyLoader = new FakeLoadForSurvey();
Survey surveyToLoad = null;

surveyLoader.Load(surveyLoader);
```

Then `surveyToLoad` is still `null` after `Load()` returns. If you don't want that, pass it with `ref`.

Comment: This is it... I think I undersatnd why it will remain null but to be honest, that isn't a factor for me (that is something I can get to grips with later on ). For now, just knowing what youv'e explained is perfect for me to try to understand. My `Load(survey t)` in the `FakeLoadForSurvey` class actually populates the values for Survey, and they are returned :) I didn't need to use `ref`

Answer (score 2):

This code looks bad from a design point of view, since you are mixing generics with statically defined types. If you use generics, you should go all the way:

```
public interface ILoad
{
    void Load<T>(T t) where T : new();  
}

public class FakeLoadForSurvey : ILoad
{
    public void Load<T>(T t) where T : new()
    {
         t = new T();
    }
}
```

I am not sure what your intention is with the parameter you define, but it loses scope after the method, so `t` will never of any use outside of the `Load<T>` method.

Comment: Your remark about the code looking very bad might be a little over the top, OP explicitly mentions he's trying to learn. You answered exactly what he wants though.

Comment: The "bad" part is explained afterwards: mixing two concepts. Don't take it personal is a good advice to start your career with. Updated though.

Comment: I don't disagree with you, I'm just saying there's no need to be sassy, though I doubt that was your intention. No offense meant, glad you're here to help.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void Load<T>(T t) where T: Survey, new()
{
     t = (T) new Survey();            // should succeed
}
```

But with a `void` return and without `ref` on the parameter this function still won't do anything useful.

Comment: The problem with this though meansd I have to update my interface? This means every object I want to do this casting would need to be explicity stated in the same way? And so could be `public void Load<T>(T t) where T: Survey, AnotherObject, AnotherObject, AndAnother, new()` ? Also, not my downvote

Comment: Yes, move the Type param T up to the interface, not the method. That will make things go a lot smoother.